# Pi for control 20 analog outputs

Tags: gpio, modules, analog-to-digital

We need 20 analog outputs with adjustable voltage (0-20 volts), frequency (0-150 Hz), as well as adjustable maximum current, and also the ability to measure current, frequency and voltage.

How can this be implemented using PI?

I know there is an analog zero module for Pi, but it will take up all the GPIO pins and give only 8 analog outputs. In addition, it is unclear whether he can do it all.

Comment: The question is too vague (no real performance criteria) and too broad.  I think you need to do more research to identify likely solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my knowledge there is no ready to buy solution.

I would recommend to use a I2C bus with the required converters connected to it.

- D/A converters example LTC2637 is a 8-Channel, 12-Bit Digital to analog converter.
- OP amplifiers to get the correct voltage span.
- Current limiters.
- To measure the properties of:
- V - An A/D converter, example ADS1000
- A - INA219 is a I2C current sensor.
- Hz - An Arduino solution; https://tushev.org/articles/arduino/9/measuring-frequency-with-arduino

And in addition to above a lot of analog design.

Comment: Isn't LTC2309 ADC?

Comment: You are right, I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi is a great way to process data especially if the desired output is digital (Binary) in the physical form, it is however less able to handle analogue inputs and outputs.

To assist the Pi, HATs/processors can be connected via the SPI or I2C interfaces. When you do this for 20 off outputs you will find that costs increase and you start to leave the world of software and enter the world of electronics, instrumentation and control.

It may be more cost effective to use purpose built I/O to handle the physical outputs RS485 interface and the Pi to supervise the control. I would reccomend something like the Fuji Electric module https://www.coulton.com/fuji_module_type_controller_pum.html